# redux todo list - stuck with 'map' error

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning Redux and doing the basic tutorial, I don't know what happen with map even that I checked carefully.
This is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This is my code:

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false 
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':  
        if (state.id !== action.id) {
          return state; 
        }
        return {
          ...state,
          completed: !state.completed
        }; 
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let initialState = []
const todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
        return [
          ...state,
          todo(undefined, action)
        ];    
   case 'TOGGLE_TODO': 
      return state.map(t => todo(t, action))      
   default:
      return state; 
  }
}

const visibilityFilter = (state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter;
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}

const todoApp = Redux.combineReducers(
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
)

let nextTodoId = 0
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text"/>
          <button type="submit"
            onClick={e => {
              e.preventDefault()
              store.dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_TODO',
                text: 'hello',
                id: nextTodoId++,
                completed: false
              })
            }}
          >
            Add Task
          </button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {this.props.todos.map(todo => 
             <li key={todo.id}>
              {todo.text}
             </li>
          )}
        </ul>
        <div>
          Show: 
          {"  "}
          <a href="#">All</a>
          {" . "}
          <a href="#">Active</a>
          {" . "}
          <a href="#">Completed</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(todoApp)

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App todos={store.getState().todos}/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}

store.subscribe(todoApp)
render()
```

Please help me.

Comment: What is the exact line where you get the error?

Comment: @Meier
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I'm not sure but I think it happens with `map()` inside `<ul>` tag, may be it's cannot read the props somewhere
here is my js bin: http://jsbin.com/conofu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the main culprit is this:

```
store.subscribe(todoApp)
```

Instead it should be this:

```
store.subscribe(render)
```

Also you should pass in an object to `combineReducer` function, like so:

```
const todoApp = combineReducers({
   todos,
   visibilityFilter
})
```

See this [link](https://jsbin.com/qobatixafu/edit?html,js,output) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

your store.getState() returns undefined.

there is no

```
store.getState().todos
```

therefore, you can't map something that undefined.

your store creation is wrong.
to combine a reducers, do it like this. (please note the "{" )

```
Redux.combineReducers(
  {
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
  }
)
```

your store.subscribe will also provide another error.
it will call the store with action = undefined.
do it with the following method :
(taken from http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html)

```
let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log(store.getState())
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a check for the todo property before using map as it may be undefined at the initial state

```
<ul>
      { this.props.todos && this.props.todos.map(todo => 
         <li key={todo.id}>
          {todo.text}
         </li>
      )}
    </ul>
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wajadiposa/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Comment: I tried but  it's not get the state when I clicked button (dispatch ADD_TODO action)
By the way, what happens with Dan lesson on egghead, I did check o this, and find nothing 
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-react-todo-list-example-adding-a-todo?course=getting-started-with-redux#/tab-transcript

Comment: The probelm is that you reducers not not combined correctly,  As @GrandJulivan has already pointed out. However, it still gives an error after that